# How to test the "with grant option" clause in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to learn Granting Privileges in SQL, and I use SQL Server to take an exercise. But when I created two users for a database named db_SPJ to test the "with grant option" clause, I have some difficities in how to login with the user I created.

```
    use db_SPJ;

    CREATE LOGIN U1 WITH PASSWORD='U1';
    CREATE USER U1 FOR LOGIN U1;

    CREATE LOGIN U2 WITH PASSWORD='U2';
    CREATE USER U2 FOR LOGIN U2;

    -- I have created a table named S
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON S TO U1;

    -- use u1, but how ?
    GRANT INSERT ON S TO U2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The situation is that when I want to use user U1 to grant privileges to user U2, I have to login in the database with user U1. So what should I do? Please any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to logging in as another user to test permissions, you can use `EXECUTE AS`:

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'U2';
GO
```

After testing, use `REVERT` to return the original security context:

```
REVERT;
```